# How to handle history limit of 100 for my own shell's history function

Tags: arrays, c, shell, for-loop, history

here is my problem: I am building my own shell and I implemented a history function, only problem is that the history array can only take 100 values, the last 100 values which means that when it goes over 100 the first value gets removed, every value moves back one index and the last value gets the 100th place. My only problem is that whatever I try the rest of my program starts bugging ( hence the commented lines ) Any way to make this work?

Here is my code:

```
void hist_add(const char *cmd)
{
    if(history_counter<100){
    strcpy(history_array[history_counter].command_stored, cmd);
    history_array[history_counter].command_number = 1111;
    history_counter++;
    }
//    else {
//        for(int j=0;j<100;j++){
//            strcpy(history_array[j].command_stored, history_array[j+1].command_stored);
//        }
//        strcpy(history_array[history_counter].command_stored, cmd);
//        history_array[history_counter].command_number = 1111;
//        history_counter++;
//    }
}
```

P.S: command_number is 1111 for every command so far because I'm implementing it next.

Comment: So I should have it loop until it gets to 99 instead?

Comment: Writing answer, please wait.

Comment: My recommendation is that you don't shift elements. Instead use the modulo operation to have the counter (array index) wrap around from `99` to `0` again. Sure you need a special case when walking backwards in the histore (going from `0` to `99`) but generally that's easier (and much less work) than to shift every element each time you add a new command to the history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There will be 99 moves, not 100 moves, to shift elements of 100-element array by one. The last 1 move is omitted because it is putting one element to out of the array.
- The shift is dropping one element. now using `history_counter` as index is wrong because the count should be decremented according to the drop.

Fixed code is:

```
    else {
        for(int j=0;j+1<100;j++){ /* use j+1<100, not j<100, to avoid out-of-range access */
            strcpy(history_array[j].command_stored, history_array[j+1].command_stored);
        }
        history_counter--; /* decrement history_counter according to the drop */
        strcpy(history_array[history_counter].command_stored, cmd);
        history_array[history_counter].command_number = 1111;
        history_counter++;
    }
```

Or omitting matching decrement and increment, it can be written like this:

```
    else {
        for(int j=0;j+1<100;j++){ /* use j+1<100, not j<100, to avoid out-of-range access */
            strcpy(history_array[j].command_stored, history_array[j+1].command_stored);
        }
        /* use history_counter-1 instead of history_counter */
        strcpy(history_array[history_counter-1].command_stored, cmd);
        history_array[history_counter-1].command_number = 1111;
    }
```

`j+1<100` can be written as `j<100-1`. Using constant value (maybe macro) instead of the magic number `100` will improve your code more.

Comment: So what would the code look like if we still needed the count to display the actual command's count. Like only 100 commands but indexes 319 to 419 for example

Comment: Getting rid of the history_counter-- but keeping the history_counter++ would do the trick?

Comment: I would add another variable to track the acutal command's count beside the variable `history_counter`, which is used to track the number of commands *in the array*.

Comment: Okay! So adding it all the way to the struct?

Comment: Not using `history_counter--;` and changing the index for new command to `100-1` will also work.